# How can I name the products of the hydration of 3,5-dimethylhept-2-ene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols

I know that the hydration of 3,5-dimethylhept-2-ene leads to several products, of which one is:

[image: Reaction scheme]

Is this called 3-oxo-3,5-dimethylheptane?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this called 3-**oxo**-3,5-dimethylheptane?

Not quite ;)

The prefix **oxo** is used if a compound has a $\ce{C=O}$ group and another group with a higher precedence that would give the **suffix** of the name.

[image: impossible structure]

If is quite obvious that there can't be an **oxo** substituent at the carbon atom that already bears the methyl group.

But you were pretty close!

The reaction with water under acidic conditions will be initiated by addition of a proton to the double bond. Of the two possible cations, the tertiary cation will be formed. When water adds as a nucleophile, you will obtain a **3-hydroxy** compound.